# Cypress sending otp to login on email, how to extract otp from email

Tags: javascript, cypress

While doing login test. Login is sending otp on linked email id and basically i want to login to email and extract mail body contents and from that extract otp.

Config.js, folder structure and email code

Comment: Which email vendor are you using, ex: gmail, mailosaur

Comment: I recommend you try [this solution](https://levz0r.medium.com/how-to-poll-a-gmail-inbox-in-cypress-io-a4286cfdb888). We use it successfully.

Comment: Gmail-testers is working fine for me. Thank you.